# Handling non existing methods using Javascript Proxy ES6 feature

Tags: javascript, methods, ecmascript-6

I am trying to have a function that can accept as many undeclared methods one after the other as possible like this: `myDefinedFunction.method1.method2.method3.method4`. I currently made it work using the ES6 proxy feature like this:

```
return new Proxy(new Client(), {
    get: function (target, property, receiver) {
        if (target.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            return target[property];
        } else {
            return "Ok";
        }
```

The client is a constructor function which has some methods defined so I use return target[property] to have access to them. Now I can finally do myDefinedFunction.method1 and get an OK. The problem is that I don't know how to now check if there was a method2 called by method1. If I don't return anything on the else portion of the code, `myDefinedFunction.method1.method2` crashes my program because method1 is undefined. Trying to return a new Proxy and return newProxy.method2 also does not work due to the fact that I have not yet returned method1 and it is undefined. My code requires being able to read how many methods were called and what name they had. How is that possible?

Comment: Returning a function that returns the `receiver` should work. https://jsfiddle.net/8wtuwtco/1/